# Importing Testim Junit xml to Xray failed with message Error creating issues in Jira

Tags: xml, junit, jira-xray, testim.io

I'm trying to import JUnit XML generated through Testim with Jenkins and received following error.

```
Starting XRAY: Results Import Task...
##########################################################
####     Xray is importing the execution results      ####
##########################################################
File found: C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\TestimTestPro\testim-tests-report.xml
Starting to import results from testim-tests-report.xml
ERROR: Step ‘Xray: Results Import Task’ failed: Unable to confirm Result of the upload..... Upload Failed! Status:400 Response:{"error":"Error creating issues in Jira!"}
```

Following is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="selenium run" tests="1" failure="0" timestamp="2023-06-30T04:52:26.555Z" skipped="0" failure-evaluating="0">
    <testcase name="test1" classname="testim.io.test" time="123.758" ownedBy="Staysure Automation" ownerEmail="automationteam@staysure.co.uk">
      <system-out>https://app.testim.io/#/project/9GScCUXVSOmXaUeDNvKA/branch/master/test/0gEraRql06D0MQdm?result-id=mCda0xgIGFUtfn2f</system-out>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Jenkins Pipeline
[image]

Xray results upload step

```
stage('Upload xray test results') {
        step([$class: 'XrayImportBuilder', endpointName: '/junit', importFilePath: 'testim-tests-report.xml', importInParallel: 'false', importToSameExecution: 'false', projectKey: 'SPT', serverInstance: '<<<<CLOUD>>>>', testExecKey: 'SPT-3082', testPlanKey: 'SPT-3081'])
    };
```

I'm using Xray in Jira cloud and results uploading is working fine with same xray serverInstance with credentials for cypress cucumber json.

Looking for a solution to upload the execution report with new Xray Jira ticket

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more info so we can help you out? 1) are you using Xray on Jira server/datacenter or on Jira cloud? 2) can you share the exact jenkins configuration you're using, like a screenshot of it? 3) Can you please confirm that the user that you're using to upload the results can create Test and Test Execution issues on the target Jira project, by going there and creating manually those issues (the content is irrelevant)?

Comment: Thanks for helping me to sort this issue @Sérgio, I've updated the question. I'm using Jira cloud and I've been using the same user (serverInstance) for Cypress cucumber results upload and its creating Xray test execution results in Jira without any issue.

Comment: On the targer project SPT on Jira, can you please create manually a Test issue through the UI? And a Test Execution issue? Does that work?

Comment: Can you try changing `failure="0"` to `failures="0"`? (on `testsuite`) That seems to be the format, possibly causing issues with Xray (see [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/developer-for-zos/14.1?topic=formats-junit-xml-format))

Comment: @Sérgio I could be able to create issue for step during manual xray execution.

Comment: @Atlow I just manually changed it and still Xray was rejecting the XML file.

Comment: I guess it's something related to your Jira environment. I would recommend reaching out Xray support team (https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) directly, so they can see this with you in more detail.

Comment: Thanks @Sérgio, The issue was fixed after adding properties tag with Xray test ID manually into output junit xml. The execution is also perfectly displayed in Xray side, linked to its original test ID. So now I'm trying to add the same tag from Testim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to upload the results from JUnit XML to Xray after adding properties tag with test key as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="selenium run" tests="1" failure="1" timestamp="2023-06-30T07:10:08.937Z" skipped="0" failure-evaluating="0">
    <testcase name="test1" classname="testim.io.test" time="253.413" ownedBy="Staysure Automation" ownerEmail="automationteam@staysure.co.uk">
      <system-out>https://app.testim.io/#/project/9GScCUXVSOmXaUeDNvKA/branch/master/test/0gEraRql06D0MQdm?result-id=P2folrIsYwSNXOYr</system-out>
      <failure message="Step Failed: Element not found More info at: https://app.testim.io/#/project/9GScCU/branch/master/test/0gEraRql?result-id=P2folrIsY"/>
        <properties>
          <!-- using a custom "test_key" property -->
          <property name="test_key" value="SPT-4323" />
        </properties>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Since the XML did not provide a link to the test case that was running, I assume that the Xray was rejecting it. I'm currently attempting to add this tag from Testim side to JUnit XML.

[image]

Comment: First, glad it worked out. Anyway, it should work without that property you specified; that property is used if you want to report results for an existing Test issue. Otherwise, if we don't provide it, Xray will autoprovision Test issues for your, one for each <testcase> element. If it can't do that, as in your original request, then there's some issue with the Jira instance/integration that only Xray support can help you out understand what might be happening exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the very late reply. I think Testim now support Xray out of the box. It should work flawlessly once you complete integration with required parameters such as: Jira username, Jira API token, XRay client ID, XRay client secret, URL.

Please refer to the screenshot and documentation below.

- Documentation: https://help.testim.io/docs/xray-integration
- Screenshot: [Testim Xray integration out of the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ4ts.png)